# Почему не создается база данных на основе sqlite Flask ? Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, flask

Проблема в том, что база данных не создаётся, я набираю в терминале IDE:

```
from Main import db.create_all()
```

После чего выдается такая ошибка:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Сам код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.bd"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/about')
def abouts_page():
    return render_template("about.html")



if __name__=='__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```